# Fix a Menu bar and Logo in WordPress

Tags: html, wordpress, css, menu

I'm facing logo and menu bar alignment no my website.
how can i fix it? sharing images below.
[image]

I want to make changes as below image..

[image]

What HTML or CSS code that I should Write ?

Comment: What is the exact problem you want to fix?

Comment: I want to make my logo left align and make menu bar full length from right to left. Just I've showed you in my second image (I want logo left aligned above the menu bar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing our discussion from **wordpress.stackexchange.com** [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/207151) and [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/207571), if I get it right, what you are trying to do is having the same menu you have when you resize the browser's window size to `1180px`, where the logo goes to the center, but instead of having this only when you resize the window to `1180px`, you want to have this type of disposal at all time, meaning having the `1180px` menu as the site's default menu.

### First

So in order to do this, we need to remove the current CSS for the default menu when the screen size is bigger than > `1180px`. To do this, go to - `style.css:1006` (meaning go to the file `style.css` line `1006`), and remove the following CSS:

> Absolute path for this file - `http://www.norenge.com/wp-content/themes/accesspress-store/style.css`

```
#site-branding {
    width: 20%;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    min-height: 60px;
}
```

---

### Second

Next thing we need to set the style for the menu when it gets at `1180px` as the new default menu. In order to do this, go to: - `responsive.css:48`, an remove the media queries around the code, which currently the code it's something like this:

> Absolute path for this file - `http://www.norenge.com/wp-content/themes/accesspress-store/css/responsive.css?ver=4.3.1`

```
@media (max-width: 1180px) {
    #site-branding {
        float: none;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        max-width: 320px;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

And you need to remove the `@media query` or just put the code outside the `@media query`, to be only like this:

```
#site-branding {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    max-width: 320px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

---

### Third and last

At last, fix the menu centering disposal, go to - `style.css:4328` and remove the `float:right;` property from the id `#menu`:

> Absolute path for this file - `http://www.norenge.com/wp-content/themes/accesspress-store/style.css`

```
#menu {
    float: right;        /* <- REMOVE THIS LINE */
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
```

With this being done, the supposed menu from the size `1180px` will now become the main default menu. Good luck! :)

Comment: Thank you so much it was perfect.

Comment: How can i place logo in left side ?

Comment: Add this bit of CSS code from this link: http://jsfiddle.net/k5nh23np , like, at the very end of your CSS file, so in case you want to remove it later, you know where to look for it.

Comment: Thanks it works now, You're amazing.. Thanks a ton !! Three more issues left ,1) Now i can't see "Call to action button on top above the login option. It appears only after login into account. why? 2) I want to remove search bar from the top left side and place right top under the  login option. 3) I can' t see tickers on the top bar ( It only appears after logged into account why?

Comment: http://demo.accesspressthemes.com/accesspress-store/  < shared you a link I want to put exactly like they placed in a demo site (Search bar, login, call to action and cart and ticker)

Comment: Glad it helped @NiravDarji :) See, you need to see that this type of questions are too extensible. Modify one thing or another, I can walk you through it, but modifying big chunks of code will become too extensive, as you can tell by this answer and require testing to see how the code behaves in different situations, different screen sizes and all of that, it's a process that takes work, time and effort, even more working blindly like this. I suggest you learn at least the basics of HTML, CSS and try to make the changes yourself, then when you have a question, you can post it here on the site.

Comment: Okay I got you now, Thanks for the help !

Comment: Help Needed, facing logo position issue in firefox and IE browsers. (it shows correctly in Chrome and Edge.

Comment: [Create a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and explain with details what's the problem you're facing, if needed, link this question as a context to it.

Comment: It doesn't let me ask more questions , It says you have reached your limit

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS for the logo:

```
.site-logo { 
    position: absolute;
    top:-55px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left: -150px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to move the following HTML,

```
<a class="site-logo" href="http://www.norenge.com/">
  <img src="http://www.norenge.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Oranemart-accesspress_store-logo.png" alt="Capital's First Online Super Store"> 
</a>
```

to be an immediate descendant of the `<section class="home_navigation"` element. Then apply `text-align: center;` to that same section element and it achieves the look you're asking for.

Comment: can you help me with php code for the same?

Comment: Wordpress usually has a template file that is in a .php extension and once inside you will see HTML in that file as well.  You shouldn't need to add any additional PHP, only move the HTML around to realign your logo. The file may be named something like header.php.

Comment: yes , I can see that file named header.php. should i put this code inside it?

Comment: Unfortunately, without seeing the files and code I cannot really be certain if that's where the adjustment is needed. You'll need to find the .php files that contain the <section> code and move the HTML from there.

Comment: Just shared my header.php code

Comment: Ok, that is the correct file. The php code that generates your logo is `<?php accesspress_store_admin_header_image() ?>` and you'll want to move that to the area I specified earlier.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php
/**
 * The header for our theme.
 *
 * Displays all of the <head> section and everything up till <div id="content">
 *
 * @package AccessPress Store
 */
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
    <head>
        <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
        <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>">
        <?php wp_head(); ?>
    </head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">
<header id="mastheads" class="site-header" role="banner">
    <?php if (as_before_top_header_enabled()): ?>
        <div class="before-top-header">
            <div class="ak-container clearfix">
                    <?php accesspress_ticker_header_customizer(); ?>
                    
                    <?php
                    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
                        global $current_user;
                        get_currentuserinfo();
                        ?>
                        <div class="welcome-user">
                            <span class="line">|</span>
                            <?php _e('Welcome ', 'accesspress-store'); ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id')); ?>" class="my-account">
                                <span class="user-name">
                                    <?php echo $current_user->display_name; ?>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                            <?php _e('!', 'accesspress-store'); ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php }
                    ?>

                    <?php if (is_active_sidebar('header-callto-action')): ?>
                        <div class="header-callto">
                            <?php dynamic_sidebar('header-callto-action') ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    
                
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="top-header clearfix">
        <div class="ak-container clearfix">


            <!-- Cart Link -->
            <?php
            if (is_woocommerce_activated()):
                echo accesspress_wcmenucart();
            endif;
            ?>
            <?php
            if (function_exists('YITH_WCWL')) {
                $wishlist_url = YITH_WCWL()->get_wishlist_url();
                ?>
                <a class="quick-wishlist" href="<?php echo $wishlist_url; ?>" title="Wishlist">
                    <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
                    <?php echo "(" . yith_wcwl_count_products() . ")"; ?>
                </a>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
            <div class="login-woocommerce">
                <?php
                if (is_user_logged_in()) {
                    global $current_user;
                    get_currentuserinfo();
                    ?>

                    <a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( home_url() ); ?>" class="logout">
                        <?php _e(' LogOut', 'accesspress-store'); ?>
                    </a>
                    <?php
                } else {
                    ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id')); ?>" class="account">
                        <?php _e('LogIn', 'accesspress-store'); ?>
                    </a>
                <?php }
                ?>
            </div>

            <!-- if enabled from customizer -->
            <?php if (!get_theme_mod('hide_header_product_search')) { ?>
                <div class="search-form">
                    <?php get_search_form(); ?>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <section class="home_navigation">
        <div class="inner_home">
            <div class="ak-container clearfix">                        
                <div id="site-branding" class="clearfix">
                    <?php accesspress_store_admin_header_image() ?>
                </div><!-- .site-branding -->
                <div class="right-header-main clearfix">
                    <div class="right-header clearfix">
                        <!-- if enabled from customizer -->
                        <div id="toggle">
                            <div class="one"></div>
                            <div class="two"></div>
                            <div class="three"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <div id="menu">
                            <?php
                            if (is_page('checkout') && get_theme_mod('hide_navigation_checkout')) {
                                
                            } else {
                                ?>
                                <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
                                    <a class="menu-toggle">
                                        <?php _e('Menu', 'accesspress-store'); ?>
                                    </a>
                                    <?php
                                    wp_nav_menu(array(
                                        'theme_location' => 'primary',
                                        'container_class' => 'store-menu',
                                        'fallback_cb' => 'custom_fallback_menu',
                                            )
                                    );
                                    ?>
                                </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
                            <?php } ?>
                        </div> 
                    </div> <!-- right-header -->
                </div> <!-- right-header-main -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </section><!--Home Navigation-->
</header><!-- #masthead -->
<div id="content" class="site-content">
>> this is my header.php code
```